# A good sorting algo for this particular usecase

Tags: c++, sorting

```
struct Object {
    int16_t order = 0;
};
```

I have a std::list of Object instances, which I want to sort based on an 'order' member variable.

- smaller order values are placed earlier in the list.
- While looping, if the current order value is the same as an existing one, I think it should be placed before that existing one, so that I don't have to continue looking at the rest elements of the list.
- The list can have a maximum of 1024 items.

I'm looking for an algo that will allow me to sort the list in the least amount of iterations, or something close to that. A naive approach that I have now results in a triangular amount of iterations, which for 1024 is:
    (1024(1024 + 1)) / 2 = 524,288

Comment: What about `std::sort`? Sounds like you are just sorting a set of `int16_t`. Maybe there's extra complexity I'm not spotting.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux if by list OP means `std::list` then `std::list::sort()` instead

Comment: For a bog-standard use case like this surely just use `std::list::sort`. It knows what to do and how best to do it. Why do you think this won't be good enough? Do you have some data?

Comment: I feel... dumb. I was looking at the reference info for std::list, and somehow missed the sort member function. Gad! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort

Comment: I don't see anything special or particular about your case. It looks just like a regular sort. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a member sort method - [`std::list::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) with appropriate comparator:

```
int main() {
    std::list<Object> objects{
        Object{4}, Object{2}, Object{6}, Object{7}, Object{42}
    };

    objects.sort([](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return lhs.order < rhs.order;
    });
}
```

Comment: std::list::sort has complexity of "n log n". How many iterations is that for 1024? Is it 10,240?

Comment: @Dess if you data is not prearranged somehow I doubt you can sort it faster.

Comment: @Slava: n log n is good enough. I'm just curious about the amount of iterations of the max entries of 1024. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Dess you can't inferr the number of iterations from the complexity. Because the answer is `k * 1024 log 1024 f(1024)` where `k` is a constant and `f(n)` is a function with an order less than `log n`. And that just applies if `1024` is an average case.

Comment: @Dess What do you mean by *iteration*? A comparison, a swap, a traverse one element further? Possible merge functions (given the likely possibility that `std::list::sort` uses MergeSort)? Possible recursive call stack? You need to be more specific

Comment: @Fureeish: How many times will the comparison function be called for 1024 items. Don't have a PC handy at the moment to test.

Comment: @Dess it will depend on the exact data. You can actually check it easily by yourself! See [this code](https://pastebin.com/ejRuJ3xr). You can simply write a loop that will randomise 1024 elements and run couple of tests yourself. Then compare the results.